# Error while submitting PySpark Application through Livy REST API

Tags: rest, pyspark, apache-nifi, livy

I want to submit a Pyspark application to Livy through REST API to invoke HiveWarehouse Connector. Based on this answer in Cloudera community

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-Submit-Spark-Application-through-Livy-REST-API/ta-p/247502

I created a test1.json as follows

```
{
"jars": ["hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar"],
"pyFiles": ["pyspark_hwc-1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78.zip"],
"file": ["test1.py"]
}
```

and call InvokeHTTP. But I get this error ""Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 224] (through reference chain: org.apache.livy.server.batch.CreateBatchRequest[\"file\"

I think the 'file' field with test1.py is wrong. Can anyone tell me how to submit this?
This works with a simple spark-submit test1.py

All suggestions are welcome

Comment: At first glance, this post seems a good start for those who like Python _(I'm not one of these)_ https://www.statworx.com/ch/blog/access-your-spark-cluster-from-everywhere-with-apache-livy/ >> also deals with _curl_ for submitting a "batch"

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter corrected link

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have tried with curl also. Same error. I need to know exactly  what  fields  have what  parameters ?

Comment: And the Apache Livy official documentation for the REST API (link above, found from Google) is rather explicit about which fileds are "maps" (Structs of nested key/value fields), which are  "lists" (Arrays of Strings) and which are not (i.e. Strings).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following works 
For basic Hive access the following works use the below JSON

```
   {
      "file":"hdfs-path/test1.py"
   }
```

For Hive LLAP access use JSON as below

```
   {
    "jars": ["<path-to-jar>/hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar"],
    "pyFiles": ["<path-to-zip>/hive_warehouse_connector/pyspark_hwc-1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78.zip"],
    "file": "<path-to-file>/test3.py"
    }
```

Interestingly when I put the zip in the "archives" field it gives error. It works for the  "pyFiles" field  though as shown above